# Count similar values of a column, show output with Value and Row count. Also retain the order

Tags: sql-server

I have data like this

```
Id      Txt
------------
1   KK
2   KK
3   AA
4   JJ
5   JJ
6   JJ
```

`Id` column is an identity key. I want the results grouped by `Txt` column values and show the row count but the ordering should be retained.

Expected result:

```
2     KK
1     AA
3     JJ
```

Count with original ordering of `Txt` column.

Comment: This is not a code service;  please provide what you have attempted

Comment: Is there a possibility that multiple of the same `Txt` values will have other values between them (e.g. add a new row containing `7,AA` to your set) - if so, what defines the order? Earliest `Id`? Latest `Id`? *Average* `Id`?

Comment: There is no *ordering* unless you **explicitly specify** an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` ....

Comment: Hello Damien sir, no this is not possible. The same Txt values will come together. Once the Txt value changes it will not have same value again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (please click the tick next to answer if you like it):

```
create table #tmp
(
    id int identity(1,1)
    , name varchar(10)
)

insert into #tmp values ('kk'), ('kk'),('ss'), ('mm'),('mm'),('mm')

select count(id), name from #tmp
group by name
order by min(id)

drop table #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:-

```
SELECT COUNT(id), Txt
FROM YOUR_TABEL
GROUP BY Txt
```

Comment: Group by Txt will not solve the problem sir. The ordering should be according to the data already present in table. Moreover if we dont write Group By Txt, the sql itself will show grouping by Txt column values. Anyway thanks ):